# Active Directory authentication with c# (encoding issue)

Tags: c#, windows, active-directory, windows-server-2008, windows-authentication

I have a problem authenticating my user against Active Directory. I am trying to authenticate my user via `PrincipalContext`.

My issue is that when user password contains non-ASCII character validation fails even with the correct credentials. But I have this problem only on my prod environment. It works just fine on UAT and development environments.

How can I resolve this issue? Is there any setting for AD has anything to do with this?

Comment: Check the culture info of your credentials against those provided through AD.

Comment: Thanks for reply, but PrincipalContext.ValidateCredentials() does not take any argument about culture

Comment: Is this a web project by any chance?

Comment: That's true, it's a web project, actually I was looking for a generic solution, because we plan this for a infrastructure module, but now I will be happy for web-only solutions to save the day.

Answer (score 0):

try to change the password encoding to UTF-8

Answer (score 0):

It is a shot in the dark, but hear me out. This is why I asked if this was a web project. I had a similar problem with identical symptoms. A user came to me saying he couldn't login in my website. Turns out he had "special" characters in his password. It didn't make sense, but after disabling custom errors I realized the error was due to ASP.NET Request Validation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh882339%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

> Request validation is a feature in ASP.NET that examines an HTTP
>   request and determines whether it contains potentially dangerous
>   content. In this context, potentially dangerous content is any HTML
>   markup or JavaScript code in the body, header, query string, or
>   cookies of the request. ASP.NET performs this check because markup or
>   code found in the URL query string, cookies, or posted form values
>   might have been added to the request for malicious purposes.

Pretty much everything that looked like a tag got flagged and runtime threw an exception way before my code had a chance to validate user's password.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the idea, I will check the request status.